# Attending a conference dinner

Tags: conference

I have registered for a conference, but there is additional registration fee for a conference dinner. Since I am from developing country and I haven't got a refund source, I find it expensive. Can I go to the restaurant and order something cheaper for myself?

Comment: Conference dinners that I can remember are usually catered, or have a set menu at a restaurant. In those cases you likely can't do what you suggest. You might ask the organizers if you could get a discount, or not attend that event.

Comment: Do you have to go to the conference dinner, or is it a special event?

Comment: There's likely to be a number of other attendees who find the dinner too expensive, or just aren't interested in highly organized events like that.  So you can probably find some other people who want to go somewhere else, and have dinner with them.  Perhaps you can find someone local who knows where to find good food that's cheap.  It can be a nice way to meet people.

Comment: In every conference I have attended, the cost of participating to the "social banquet" is included in the registration fees. You only pay extra if you want to pay for an additional place, say if you want to bring your partner (who might not be registered to the conference).

Comment: Some of the best dinners I've had at conferences have been with the other people not going to the conference dinner.

Comment: @TheWanderer For my field, it's almost always extra, because it's more of either a social/fundraising event than a "Do you want to eat food with people at the conference?" event.

Comment: @TheWanderer There are conferences where the banquet is not included on the 1-day registration, only the full registration. Which is obvious because you may not be there on that day. On the other hand, the OP might try asking around at the conference if anybody has an extra ticket, if they have to leave early or decided to go somewhere else that night...

Answer (score 11):

You’d have to check with the conference organizers. However, usually when such dinners are organized, the conference has already contracted a reduced price per attendee in exchange for a volume order with a fairly limited menu selected in advance. You usually don’t get to order à la carte off the restaurant’s menu.